# How to skip the rollback for DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with JPA and Hibernate. I have a table with one unique constraint because I would like to avoid having multiple rows.

In my business logic method, I have to save multiple rows and I would like to add the `@Transactional` because I need to rollback in case of some errors occurring during some saves.

For me, the DataIntegrityViolationException (the constraint is violated) is not an error and in this case I would like to avoid the rollback (if the row already exist I need to go on with the others saves).

I tried multiple solution just to setup my `@Transactional` to skip the rollback in case of DataIntegrityViolationException (for example in this case `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class, noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)`) but this not works and I receive:

> UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because
> it has been marked as rollback-only

Any idea?

Comment: Not following the issue.   If you have a constraint you are knowingly violating then this is exactly what it is supposed to do.   Just rolling back part of a change completely defeats the whole point of having transactions.     If the row is already there don't try to insert it.   Just insert into the related tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)` is going to work, but you have to put it on your repository method, not the service one.

```java
public interface SomeRepo extends JpaRepository<_, _> {
    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    void someUpdate(...);
}
```

The reason the rollback does not occur in your case is that the exception gets thrown from the transactional proxy that is not marked to skip those types of errors.

I wrote an [article](https://dev.to/kirekov/spring-data-transactional-caveats-19di) about this nuance. Perhaps, that will help to clarify the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try just to surround your statement that throws the `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception with a `try catch` and in the `catch` block just print the error avoiding to throw a `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception followed by a rollback.