# Data not getting saved in DB even after flush and @Transactional

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to save some data in a database. I have a native query for my save function and, when I execute it, there is no exception thrown but the data is not visible in the DB.

```java
public interface DBConnection extends JpaRepository<Enitty, Long> {

    String query = "INSERT INTO My_table (MESSAGE_CODE, MESSAGE, LANGUAGE, ID) VALUES(?1,?2,?3,?4)";

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
    void save(String a, String r, String t, String s);

}
```

Based on other SO question, the data was probably not flushing or not getting committed, but I have called `flush()` function and if I understand Spring-JPA correctly then `@Transactional` should commit once the transaction is completed, but both of them are failing, (I have used both `Transactional` javax and spring.)

Also note there is not exception being thrown at all, and no logs to help what issues it's facing during persistance

```java
    @Transactional
    private void saveToDB(List<List<String>> records) {
        int count = 0;
        for (List<String> record : records) {
            try {
                dbConnection.save(record.get(0), record.get(1), record.get(2), record.get(3));
                dbConnection.flush();
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("element probably exists " + record);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error record is " + record);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip the rollback for DataIntegrityViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203663/how-to-skip-the-rollback-for-dataintegrityviolationexception)

Comment: but there is not exception as well, if there was any it would be fine

Comment: Do you mean to say neither of the two `catch` block is entered when you run the code? Have you setup a breakpoint in each of them?

Comment: yes, it's coming to neither and yes i have set up debug point on both of them